# Making a Quiz Game (Python)

Tags: python, class

I am a beginner in Python Programming having just completed my procedural level programming in python.

I am making a quiz game using Object-Oriented Programming. I came across a problem which I am not able to get.

Here is my code:

```
from question_model import Question
from data import question_data

question_bank = []

for i in question_data:
    for j in range(0, 13):
        questions_ans = Question(i[j].key, i[j].value)
        question_bank.append(questions_ans)

print(question_bank)
```

The `question_model` file is:

```
class Question:

def __init__(self, text, answer):
    self.text = text
    self.answer = answer
```

The `question_data` list is :

```
question_data = [
{"text": "A slug's blood is green.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "The loudest animal is the African Elephant.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "The total surface area of a human lungs is the size of a football pitch.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, "
         "you are free to take it home to eat.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, "
         "you are entitled to a state funeral.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "Google was originally called 'Backrub'.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "A few ounces of chocolate can to kill a small dog.", "answer": "True"}
]
```

And here is my code image:

[image]

The `question_bank` list is also empty as seen in the console. It should give the location address, didn't it?

And also, the `question_data` is a variable in `data` file consisting of a list of dictionaries.
I am trying to iterate through the list of dictionaries so I have used 2 **for-loops**.

The code is showing no error otherwise it can give me some hints about where I am wrong.
Is my way of iterating and appending correct?

Can you point out the error in the above code?

Comment: Give some sample for how your question_data list of dictionary looks like

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add instances of Question class to your question_bank list:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, text, answer):
        self.text = text
        self.answer = answer

question_bank = []
question_data = [
{"text": "A slug's blood is green.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "The loudest animal is the African Elephant.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "The total surface area of a human lungs is the size of a football pitch.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, "
         "you are free to take it home to eat.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, "
         "you are entitled to a state funeral.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "Google was originally called 'Backrub'.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.", "answer": "True"},
{"text": "No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.", "answer": "False"},
{"text": "A few ounces of chocolate can to kill a small dog.", "answer": "True"}
]

for item in question_data:
    question_bank.append(Question(item["text"], item["answer"]))

print(question_bank)
```

However, if you want to get question and answer from these objects you have to use attributes of these class:

```
for item in question_bank:
    print(item.text)
    print(item.answer)
```

**Output**

```
A slug's blood is green.
True
The loudest animal is the African Elephant.
False
Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.
True
The total surface area of a human lungs is the size of a football pitch.
True
In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, you are free to take it home to eat.
True
In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, you are entitled to a state funeral.
False
It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.
True
You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.
False
Google was originally called 'Backrub'.
True
Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.
True
No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.
False
A few ounces of chocolate can to kill a small dog.
True
```